# Passing events and arguments into another function

Tags: javascript

In order to pass the event information to the change function, I have to call change function from the event listener without parenthesis.

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('boxes');

for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
  boxes[i].addEventListener('click', change, false);
}

function change(e){
  e.target.style.border = '1px solid red';
}
```

The issue comes when i then want to pass in an argument as well as passing the event. It seems when adding an argument the event fails.

How would i be able to include something like this where the event is passed to change the border but am also able to pass arguments into the function?

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('boxes');

for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
  boxes[i].addEventListener('click', change(10, 20), false);
}

function change(e, a, b){
  e.target.style.border = '1px solid red';
  console.log(a * b);
}
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it an anonymous function:

```
boxes[i].addEventListener('click', function ( e ) { change(e, 10, 20) }, false);
```

Comment: What @Paulpro said is the nearest thing to what you want, and you can not create an delegate with unknown parameters. I tried this for a day in my case sent parameters to ajax success function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var changeFn = function (e) {
    change(e, 10, 20);
};
```

now add this to your click event

```
boxes[i].addEventListener('click', changeFn, false);
```

remove event listener is simple in this case

```
boxes[i].removeEventListener('click', changeFn, false);
```